# Update table a columns using columns from table b (values of 2 columns of table b need to taken from table c)

Tags: sql-server

I need to update table A columns col3, col4, col5 and col6 by table b columns col3, col4, col5 and col6 however table b col5 and col6 values need to come from table c col1.
Means table b col5 and col6 have values in it however i need to replace them with value from table c col1 and need to update table a col5 and col6 accordingly.
table a and table b has col1 and col2 in common. i am trying something like this.

```
Update a
a.col3 = b.col3,  
a.col4 = b.col4,
a.col5 = (select col1 from table_c c where c.col2=b.col5),
a.col6 = (select col1 from table_c c where c.col2=b.col6)
from table_A a inner join table_b
on  a.col1=b.col1 and a.col2=b.col2
```

can someone help me reframe above update query?
thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you also put sample data(what it is before the update and what it will be after the update)?

Comment: @TTeeple: table a                                                  abc def 0 0 -999 -999                                           table b                                                          abc def 1 1 -sa1283 -sa4958                                     table c -sa1283 1234 -sa4958 3456                               After update table A should be like this                        table a                                                          abc def 1 1 1234 3456                                               hope this will be more clear –

Answer (score 0):

`Update a
    a.col3 = b.col3, 
    a.col4 = b.col4,
    a.col5 = c.col1,
    a.col6 = d.col1
    from table_A a inner join table_b on  a.col1=b.col1 and a.col2=b.col2
    inner join table_c c on c.col2 = b.col5
    inner join table_c d on d.col2 = b.col6`

Otherwise, use `select top 1` in subqueries.

Comment: hi when i using inner query it is returning duplicate row for every rows from table a.